# How to change domain on links but preserve the path?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, dns, userscripts

I want to redirect the link from `facebook.com/abcdef` to `m.facebook.com/abcdef` via userscript.

Using:

- `window.location.replace("https://m.facebook.com");` does not go to `m.facebook.com/abcdef`
- `window.location.replace(window.location.href.replace('https://', 'https://m.'));` does, but the page keeps loading that I can't scroll down to read without disruption.

Comment: Would something like this work? 

`window.location.replace(window.location.href.replace('https://', 'https://m.'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the meta include rules of your user script match `https://m.facebook.*` as well. Thus the user script is started after every redirection again.

Just exclude `https://m.facebook.*` from your rules or use a more specific needle in your invocation of the `replace` method, e.g. replace `'https://facebook.'` by `'https://m.facebook.'`.